# Boost on multisite

Tags: caching

I installed boost following the instruction on the project page. i managed to make it generate the html pages (in the boost cashe folder) but these pages are just not displayed. 
cannot see the boost comment at the end of page. any ideas ?

i also edit the .htaccess file , added the generated code in the right place. but problem is still there

Comment: Are you sure you are not logged in? Boost works for anonymous requests only.

Comment: yes.. very sure am logged out :) .. am on turnkey Linux drupal installation.. not sure if this info may help. also the page get cashed somehow. even i disabled native caching !!

Comment: managed to make it work.. i was using the dev version, and every thing worked fine after replacing it with the latest beta version